# In Srong Loop loopback framework in config.json file when I assign any public IP its shows EADDRNOTAVAILerror

Tags: node.js, express, strongloop, loopback

```
my config file -
 "restApiRoot": "/api",
  "host": "103.6.156.11",
  "port": 3009,
  "remoting": {
    "context": false,
    "rest": {
      "normalizeHttpPath": false,
      "xml": false
    },
    "json": {
      "strict": false,
      "limit": "100kb"
    },
    "urlencoded": {
      "extended": true,
      "limit": "100kb"
    },
    "cors": false,
    "handleErrors": false
  }
}
```

Comment: only 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1 ip works.. i do not know what to do??

Comment: Look like your server is not listening on port 3009  telnet 103.6.156.11 3009 give Connection refused check if the port is open.

Comment: I resolved this issue. I have deploy loopback on amazon ec2. I assigned LAN ip instead of public IP, after that it start listening to public IP. In Amazon ec2 they assign LAN IP to different instances under public IP. It resolves my issue. We have to allow access to tcp port in our ec2 instance.